# can I include normal asp.net pages (webforms or mvc) in a Dynamic Data web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, dynamic-data

can I include normal asp.net pages (webforms or mvc) in a Dynamic Data web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep you can, just put a normal webforms file in there, it will work. Add references for any server side controls as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example of a mish-mash.

Plug-In Hybrids: ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.MVC and ASP.NET Dynamic Data Side By Side

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx